# How can I match a random number from Numpool array against my matchNum array?

Tags: actionscript-3

Ok i used the indexOf and i got it to work with this....But i posted code below this one with the random number and it doesn't work.

```
movieClip_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);

    function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var allreadyPicked:Array = [1,2,3,4,5];
        var pickedNum:Array = [3,5];


        function compareArrays(init_arr:Array, comparing_arr:Array):Array
        {
            var differenceArray_arr:Array = new Array();

            for each (var id_obj:Object in init_arr)
            {
                if (comparing_arr.indexOf(id_obj) >= 0)
                {
                    differenceArray_arr.push(id_obj);
                }
            }
            return differenceArray_arr;
        }

        trace("Matched Number " + compareArrays(allreadyPicked, pickedNum));
    }
```

But when i add my random number code it doesnt seem to work any ideas y not????

```
movieClip_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked);

function clicked(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //
    var allreadyPicked:Array = [1,5];


    //
    var numPool:Array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    var numPicked:Array = [];
    var randomCount:Number = 1;
    var r:Number;


    for (var i = 0; i < randomCount; i++)
    {
        r = Math.floor(Math.random() * numPool.length);
        numPicked[numPicked.length] = numPool.splice(r,1);
    }

    trace("Number Picked " + numPicked);
    ranNum.text = String(numPicked);


    function compareArrays(init_arr:Array, comparing_arr:Array):Array
    {
        var differenceArray_arr:Array = new Array();

        for each (var id_obj:Object in init_arr)
        {
            if (comparing_arr.indexOf(id_obj) >= 0)
            {
                differenceArray_arr.push(id_obj);
            }
        }

        return differenceArray_arr;
    }
    trace("Matched " + compareArrays(allreadyPicked, numPicked));
```

Comment: I answered your question of how to do what you wanted, and now you have changed what you wanted to do.  This is a Question and Answers site. If you just change the question each time, no one is being helped by the solutions except you. That's not the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use indexOf method of an Array to tell you if it exists and what it's index is.

example :

```
var index:int = matchNum.indexOf(numPicked);

if(index >= 0)
{
  // match exists
  // index is the index of matching element in matchNum array

}
    else
    {
        // no match
    }
```

Comment: I used the indexOf method and i had some good and bad out of it.. I re-posted my code above if u wanna check it out

Comment: This solution solved your original issue, it's no longer valid because you changed what you were doing.